# How do I change my PharoCloud appliance domain to my domain?

Tags: dns, pharocloud

I registered at PharoCloud. Now I have an appliance that serves web pages at http://mydomain.pharocloud.com

How can I serve these pages from http://mydomain.com?  The domain is registered with GoDaddy; do I need to update the hosts file somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best answer is to read the newly released entry on the subject in the Help & Docs section of PharoCloud : http://pharocloud.com/kb/tutorial/domainname